# Create QR-code from citeurl

Tags: biblatex, citing, qrcode

How can I create a QR-code by using and citing an url from a bibliography-entry with `\citeurl`?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
author = {A. Author},
title = {My Title},
url = {http://tex.stackexchange.de},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[           
  backend=biber,
  style=archaeologie,
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \qrcode{\citeurl{test}} %<---- it does’t work
  \citeurl{test} %<--- it works
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like an expansion issue. `\citeurl` does not simply dump the `url`, it does a lot of formatting as well. From within `biblatex` you can use `\thefield{url}` to access the raw URL, so that you can define a new command

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeqrurl}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\qrcode{\thefield{url}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```