# citefield inside of href

Tags: biblatex, href

I have a special field in my bibliography, called `adsurl`, and I would like to display this url in my file as a link.

However, when I try this, href throws a very weird error. It enters some sort of infinite loop where it keeps saying

```
! Undefined control sequence.
 \filename@simple ...#2\\}\fi \edef \filename@base 
                                              {#1}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
 author       = {Anne Elk},
 title        = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
 adsurl       = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.html},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[hyperref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
 \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout=false]{adsurl}
 \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{adsurl}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
 \cite{elk} %this works
 \citefield{elk}{adsurl} %this also works
 \href{\citefield{elk}{adsurl}}{ads} %this does not work
\end{document}
```

How can I get `href` to accept the output of `citefield` as url?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412924/35864 help? `\citefield` does a bit more than just 'returning' the value of the field, so it can't be used as argument to `\href`.

Comment: More relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413365/35864

Comment: @moewe, wouldn't a `DeclareFieldFormat` with a `bibhyperref` directive get the job done here?

Comment: @gusbrs You mean `\DeclareFieldFormat{adsurl}{\href{#1}{ads}}`? That would be a viable option if the link text is fixed. The `\citefield` gets a bit more awkward, though, since we have to specify the format (otherwise `\citefield` defaults to the `citefield` format): `\citefield{elk}[adsurl]{adsurl}`. If the 'ads' text ought to be variable, one would have to find a way to inject the correct text into the format (probably via a wrapper command). In that case a new `\DeclareCiteCommand` with postnote seems nicer to me.

Comment: @moewe Trickier than I thought. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @moewe: yes, thanks for the links, that helped :) if you want to write an answer, feel free, otherwise I will answer it myself in a few days.

Comment: Would you also be OK with closing it as a duplicate?

Comment: yes, after seeing the other questions... I didn't find them, because I was searching with different keywords, so I hope this question still guides some people to the right answers (duplicates are indexed by search engines, right?)

Comment: The question remains searchable even if closed as a duplicate. It only just occurred to me: If the `adsurl` is similar to the arXiv you could also check out the `eprint` field.

Comment: no, `adsurl` and `eprint` are different things and are usually both defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the links provided by moewe, I was able to fix this. So I decided to answer this so people won't have to click through to the other questions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
author       = {Anne Elk},
title        = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
adsurl       = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.html},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[hyperref,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal, skipout=false]{adsurl}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{adsurl}
\end{filecontents*}

%Here's the trick:
\DeclareCiteCommand{\ads}
 {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
 \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
 \usebibmacro{prenote}}
 {\href{\thefield{adsurl}}{ads}}
 {\multicitedelim}
 {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
 \cite{elk}
 \citefield{elk}{adsurl}
 \ads{elk}
\end{document}
```

For more explanations see the linked questions.