# Can I use \citeurl inside \href?

Tags: biblatex

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../main.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{jeff2018} said in his awesome article
\href{\citeurl{jeff2018}}{\citetitle{jeff2018}} that life is great!
\end{document}
```

This is what I have in `main.bib`:

```
@misc{jeff2018,
  title={Life Is Great},
  author={Lebowski, Jeff},
  year={2018},
  url={http://www.yegor256.com}
}
```

Can't compile. What is the right way?

Comment: Please post the contents of the entry with key `jeff2018`.

Comment: @Mico done, posted

Comment: I was going to suggest that you write `\href{\protect\citeurl{jeff2018}}{\citetitle{jeff2018}}`. Unfortunately, even though this modification lets LaTeX finish without crashing, it doesn't create the expected output, i.e., the title string )"Life is Great") isn't properly clickable. Hopefully, the maintainers of the `hyperref` and `biblatex` packages will provide more helpful answers.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430063/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413365/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412924/35864. `\href` expects something that more or less expands to a raw URL, but `\citeurl` already applies lots of formatting to the URL and so can't really be used here.

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citea}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}\boolfalse{pagetracker}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\href{\thefield{url}}{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```