# create a hyperlink by using the url stored in the bibliography reference?

Tags: biblatex, url, hyperlink, href

im wondering if i can create a hyperlink that automaticaly uses the bib file stored tag 'url' somehow? Just to prevent mistakes in linking to a reference and to a websource in the same text like:

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=nature, url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{UseCase20,
  title = {{Use-Case 2.0 ebook}},
  journal = {Ivar Jacobson International},
  year = {2014},
  month = {Jul},
  note = {[Online; accessed 25. Dec. 2018]},
  url = {https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\href{https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}{sometext} \footcite{UseCase20}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

i wold like to something like this work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=nature, url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{UseCase20,
  title = {{Use-Case 2.0 ebook}},
  journal = {Ivar Jacobson International},
  year = {2014},
  month = {Jul},
  note = {[Online; accessed 25. Dec. 2018]},
  url = {https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\href{\citeurl{UseCase20}}{sometext} \footcite{UseCase20}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

but unfortunately this breaks at l.18;

> \href{\citeurl{UseCase20}}{sometext}

**EDIT:**

MWE with all tests:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=nature, url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{UseCase20,
    title = {{Use-Case 2.0 ebook}},
    journal = {Ivar Jacobson International},
    year = {2014},
    month = {Jul},
    note = {[Online; accessed 25. Dec. 2018]},
    url = {https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413372/118709
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelink}
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
        \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
        \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\iffieldundef{postnote}
        {\href{\thefield{url}}{\printfield{title}}}
        {\href{\thefield{url}}{\thefield{postnote}}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412927/118709
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeqrurl}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\qrcode{\thefield{url}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413519/118709
\DeclareCiteCommand{\geturl}
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}\boolfalse{pagetracker}}
    {\iffieldundef{postnote}
        {\xdef\biburl{\thefield{url}}}
        {%
            \edef\geturlTmpCmd{\csfield{postnote}}%
            \expandafter\xdef\geturlTmpCmd{\thefield{url}}%
        }%
    }
    {}
    {}
\begin{document}
~\\
\citelink{sometext}{UseCase20}\footcite{UseCase20}\\
~\\
\citeqrurl{sometext}{UseCase20}\footcite{UseCase20}\\
~\\
\geturl{UseCase20}
%The \href{\biburl}{UseCase}\footcite{UseCase20}\\.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\citeurl` can't be used as argument to `\href`, you need to define your own macro, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413365/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412924/35864.

Comment: see above i tested all 3 types of macro but none makes a klickable link to the url...
the last test even breaks, so its commented.

Comment: The correct syntax for `\citelink` would have been `\citelink[sometext]{UseCase20}`. `\citeqrurl` as implemented in the linked answer was intended for a different use case and would have to be tweaked for yours. The last solution worked for me as well (even though I find it much less elegant for this use case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\citeurl` does not return the URL of the entry in question (in an expandable way), instead it is meant to print the *formatted* URL. That means that it can't be used as the URI argument for `\href`. If you want to be able to `\href` the URL of an entry to arbitrary text, the simplest way is to create a new `\cite...` macro. Since `\cite...` macros have a fixed argument structure the one below works as follows

```
\citehrefurl[<arbitrary text that is going ot be linked>]{<entrykey>}
```

You could create a new command with arbitrary arguments. Usually I strongly advise against creating new commands from `\cite...` commands via `\newcommand`, but in this case we can make an exception.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature, url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citehrefurl}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\iffieldundef{url}
     {\PackageWarning{biblatex}
        {The entry \thefield{entrykey} has no URL.\MessageBreak
         No link will be created}%
      \printfield{postnote}}
     {\href{\thefield{url}}
        {\iffieldundef{postnote}
           {\PackageWarning{biblatex}
              {Text argument missing,\MessageBreak
               using the title for entry\MessageBreak
               \thefield{entrykey}}%
            \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
           {\printfield{postnote}}}}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\citehrefurlwrap}[2]{\citehrefurl[#2]{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{UseCase20,
  title   = {Use-Case 2.0 ebook},
  author  = {Ivar Jacobson and Ian Spence and Kurt Bittner},
  date    = {2011-12},
  url     = {https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook},
  urldate = {2018-12-25},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citehrefurl{UseCase20}

\citehrefurl[some text]{UseCase20}

\citehrefurlwrap{UseCase20}{some other text}

\citeurl{UseCase20}

\href{https://www.ivarjacobson.com/publications/white-papers/use-case-ebook}{sometext}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

<sub>Sorry there is no image at the moment. I'm having trouble uploading them. Feel free to add a screenshot of the result if you like.</sub>

This is basically a slightly modified version of [jakun](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120953/jakun)'s `\citelink` from their answer to [How to create a link to a URL provided in a bib file with custom text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413365/35864) which was in turn inspired by [Create QR-code from citeurl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412924/35864).

Comment: exept the last ordinary \href link none of the above creates a click able link in my case.

Comment: @novski What *exact* result do you get instead? Do note that the `url` field in your example was faulty: It contained to much whitespace. I fixed that in my code.

Comment: sorry for that. i corrected the mwe. but i copied your mwe from this answer. and i get 3 lines of "UseCase20" and one line "sometext" only "sometext" is clickable...

Comment: Take my MWE and compile it in a new, empty folder with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. If you get bold **UseCase20** as output that means that `biblatex` failed to resolve the citation. That should have little to do with the macro itself.

Comment: @novski To see that the code above works as intended check out https://v1.overleaf.com/read/chsgpnfhwhvs.

Comment: strange i get a total different output from TexShop. Executed manualy with pdflatex it looks like yours and links the url clickable now. sorry for that. Thank you for the nice comparsion upon the different types of possabilities. And for the fast solution.

Comment: @novski Maybe TeXshop runs BibTeX instead of Biber? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: +1 Basically the same that I asked here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467262.