# Modify BibteX Style in usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have defined my bibliography style with this line in the preamble:
`\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}`. Is there a way to get the sourcecode of the bibliographystyle and provide a modified copy?

I already searched for naturemag.bst and have put it into the same directory, but using a line like `\usepackage[style=mynaturestyle]{biblatex}` while having a file named mynaturestyle.bst in the same directory does not work.

The reason why I need to hack the nature style is because some journals like SciData claim to use Nature style, but require a different formatting.

Comment: `biblatex` does not use 'classical' `.bst` files; instead, modification of style is done using LaTeX commands. The style files are called `nature.bbx` and `nature.cbx`:  you can see them for example on https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature

Comment: I suspect as it stands the question here is a duplicate of the general 'how to modify a `biblatex` style' one

Comment: If you want to submit your paper to a journal (or another publisher), do check if they can accept `biblatex` submissions before you proceed. `biblatex` requires a different workflow for publishers and is not as widely adopted as BibTeX (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864). Often journals have their own `.bst` files or at least provide some additional guidance for LaTeX users that may include hints for the bibliography style as well.

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` does not work with `.bst` files the same way classical BibTeX does. In fact if you use the default Biber backend, no `.bst` file is involved at all. (If you use BibTeX as `backend`, `biblatex` uses its `biblatex.bst`  but that does not control any formatting in the output and should not be modified.)

Instead `biblatex` styles are defined with `.bbx`, `.cbx` and optionally `.dbx` and `.lbx` files. The idea is that

- **`.bbx`** files contain the definitions for the **bibliography** style,
- **`.cbx`** files contain the definitions of the **citation** style,
- **`.dbx`** files contain additions to the **data model** (such a file is only required if a style wants to define new fields or entry types that are not present in the standard data model documented in the `biblatex` manual),
- **`.lbx`** files contain **localisation**/language definitions (`.lbx` files are only needed if the style needs to change language-dependent stuff).

The first three files (if present) are usually called `<stylename>.bbx`, `<stylename>.cbx`, `<stylename>.dbx`, while the `.lbx` files are usually called `<language>-<style suffix>.lbx` (though the naming scheme for `.lbx` files is rather recent, older styles may use other conventions, but it is usually possible to tell the language and the style from the file name).

---

The Nature style of [`biblatex-nature`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature) consists only of the two main files `nature.bbx` and `nature.cbx` (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-nature).

If you find a file `nature.bst` that has nothing to do with the output you get from `\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}`.

You can copy the `nature.bbx` and `nature.cbx` two files and rename them to `mynaturestyle.bbx` and `mynaturestyle.cbx`, respectively. Then you can go about modifying the files as you wish.

Since `.bbx` and `.cbx` files just contain normal LaTeX code, it is common not to copy the files at all, but to just apply the required redefinition in the preamble of your document (see for example [create a hyperlink by using the url stored in the bibliography reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467262/35864)).

You can find a bit more about where to put `biblatex` modifications in [Biblatex.cfg vs .cls vs .sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296732/35864).

---

There is a nice introduction to simple `biblatex` customisations at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

---

Finally, it should be noted that `biblatex` requires a different workflow from publishers than classical BibTeX or `thebibliography`, so I would only use `biblatex` in a journal submission if the publishers explicitly mentions that `biblatex` should be used. Often publishers provide some guidance for LaTeX users (when they accept LaTeX submissions at all) and quite often they include hints about the bibliography as well.