# How to create a personal citestyle from a personal bibstyle?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex

I created a personal bibstyle with **makebst** and it works perfectly fine but i'd like to use that same file to create a personal citestyle to use instead of **verbose-trad2**. Is it possible ?

Comment: That is definitely possible. Could you expand your question a bit, to make it more clear what you want? Make a small example document with one or two citations in it, show the current output, and explain what you want the output to be. That does not necessarily have to include your own `.bst` file, probably you can demonstrate what you want also with a standard style (and the solution will apply to your custom style as well).

Comment: I write in french, so my bib standard for books is : Surname, Firstname, _Title_ , Editor/Translator, Adress, Publisher, Date, page number.  My personal bibstyle does that and I want verbose citestyle to respect that order and the separation marks in the footnotes. I found a solution with some macros to redefine the separators and the order but I wanted to know if there was a more simple solution

Comment: It is still not entirely clear (to me at least) what you mean with _verbose citestyle_, how you want to incorporate this in your LaTeX code, and how this will interact with other parts of your code related to citations. For suggesting solutions or approaches it would help if you would post the code for a small document that shows your current approach, and a description of which parts of the current approach you dislike and which parts of the output you want to be different.

Comment: Note that `.bst` files (bibliography styles for BibTeX) are *completely* incompatible with `biblatex` (you mention `verbose-trad2`). There is no way to use a `.bst` produced with `makebst` together with `biblatex` and by extension with `verbose-trad2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makebst` produces `.bst` files for use with classical BibTeX. `biblatex` does not use `.bst` files for formatting (indeed if you use Biber as recommended, no `.bst` file is involved at all) instead it uses `.bbx` files for the bibliography style and `.cbx` files for the citation style. See also [How to use custom bibstyle with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174676/35864) and [Modify BibteX Style in usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527274/35864).

Since `verbose-trad2` is a `biblatex` style, you can not use it together with the `.bst` file produced by `makebst`. If you want to use `verbose-trad2` you need to write your bibliography style in `biblatex` (cf. [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864)).

But if it is possible to recreate the bibliography style you want with `makebst`, it should also be possible to recreate it in `biblatex`.